# Minimal work example for darray from breqn

Tags: equations, breqn

I was trying to use the `darray` environment from the `breqn` package but hadn't success on it.

As a mwe I would like to replace the `eqnarray` below by the `darray`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \max & & c^T x \\
  \text{s.t.} & & x \in \left\{ 0, 1 \right\}^n
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

I try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{darray}[cols={rl}]
  \max & c^T x \\
  \text{s.t.} & x \in \left\{ 0, 1 \right\}^n
\end{darray}
\end{document}
```

but got the error below

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@tempc ...let \@preamble \@empty \darray@mkpream 
                                                  #1\@percentchar 
l.5 \begin{darray}[cols={rl}]

? 
! Emergency stop.
\@tempc ...let \@preamble \@empty \darray@mkpream 
                                                  #1\@percentchar 
l.5 \begin{darray}[cols={rl}]

End of file on the terminal!
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `breqn` documentation specifies that "the `darray` environment is unfinished". Perhaps a safer alternative should be used. How about simply using an `array` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{rl}
  \max    &  c^T x \\
  \text{s.t.} & x \in \left\{ 0, 1 \right\}^n
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Same semantics, different syntax. Decide which you find easier to read.

```
\begin{equation*}
\max \left\{ c^T x \mid x \in \left\{ 0, 1 \right\}^n \right\}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]